# Usage of was/is with always

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

I came across a question which asked to fill the blank with is, am, was or were: "The puppy _______  always naughty."

I'm confused between: "The puppy was always naughty" and "The puppy is always naughty". Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct, unless we had some other context to say which tense we are dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are correct. You should use "is" in this sentence if you wish to refer the puppy as still living. Otherwise, "was" would be appropriate.

Comment: The puppy could still be alive, but no longer naughty.

Comment: @Xena James is right in his point, but please can you also add some references to your answer?